# Stuck while trying to prove $2k^3 \geq (k + 1)^3$......

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality, proof-verification, induction

how can I prove the following:

$2k^3 \geq (k + 1)^3$

This is the final part of the elaborate proof for $2^n > n^3 $ give $ n \geq 10$

I have used induction and end up with:
$ 2^{K+1} > 2k^3 $

After that we just need to prove $2k^3 \geq (k + 1)^3$, but I have no idea how to do so. :(

So how do I proceed to prove $2k^3 \geq (k + 1)^3$?

OR

Am I trying to prove $ 2^{K+1} > 2k^3 $ in a wrong manner?

Thanks for all the help in advance! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is equivalent to $((k+1)/k)^3\leq 2$ so it is equivalent to $(1+1/k)^3\leq 2$.

But the sequence $(1+1/n)^3$ decreases, so if it is $\leq 2$ in $10$ it will be also for $n\geq 10$.

Answer (score 2):

In order to prove $2k^3 \geq (k + 1)^3$ we can expand the inequality to get: $k^3 \geq 3k^2+3k+1$. **Theorem:** If $[a,b]$ is some interval, $f(a)<g(a)$, and $f'(x)≤g'(x)$ on the interval, then $f(x)<g(x)$ on the interval.
 In our case the interval is $I:= [10,\infty)$. 
 $2x \geq 3$ on $I$ and $10^2>2(10)+1$ so $x^2>2x+1$ and $3x^2>6x+3$  on $I$.
 $10^3>3(10)^2+3(10)+1$ and we know that $3x^2>6x+3$ so we can conclude that $x^3 \geq 3x^2+3x+1$. Note that I used the theorem in a sort of backwards way: I chose my inequalities based on what I need to prove. 
**Note:** My previous answer had a subtle flaw which was pointed out to me by @awllower.

Comment: Taking the limit does not allow one to deduce the inequality, however.

Comment: and why is that?

Comment: I mean: inserting finitely many terms to a sequence does not affect the limit. And the limit behaviour does not guarantee the behaviour at other points. In particular, the figure $10$ plays no particular role in your argument: it holds whenever $k\ge1,$ while the result is not true when $k=1.$

Comment: You're right about finitely many terms but I was viewing the inequality in a calculus setting. so perhaps I should've replaced $k$ with $x$.

Comment: My point is: your proof works for every $k\ge1,$ but the result is not true for $k=1.$ Isn't there something wrong?

Comment: you're right. I fixed my answer.

Comment: NP. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

By subtracting and expanding, the inequality is equivalent with $$k^3\ge 3k^2+3k+1,$$ or $$k(k^2-3k-3)\ge1.$$
When $k\ge10,$ the factor $(k^2-3k-3)$ is always greater than $1$ (in fact, this holds when $k\ge4.$) So the inequality holds.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the cubic root of both members you get

$(\sqrt[3]{2}-1) k \geqslant 1$ that holds for $k \geqslant 4$

I hope I gave the right answer to the question